# Merge CSV Files with same name, in different folders, to same name in new folder. (Excel/VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, csv, merge

Know very little about VBA from scratch, have only been using parts and piecing together, with hope of a result. Thus not much to show as example, as it is not my work.

**Background**

Community Radio Station with 3 studios, broadcasting only one at a time, depending on the shift.

The Audio playout program (RadioBoss) stores all played files in a CSV, with only a date as name on the PC that is playing the audio.
The Playout program has a feature to provide proof of broadcast  (Reports) that gathers the data from the CSV file. However it does not have a function to combine 3 studios info together, thus the result to the client is 3 PDF output files, one for every studio. The clients would like all on one document.

3 identical file names, in 3 folders.

I have contacted the software company to request additional features in the software updates. The request has been rejected for the last year.

**Problem**

I would like to combine eg. 3 CSV from every studio into one CSV that the playout software can gather the info from one file,and thus output one PDF of information.

**Criteria**

Studio1_Folder

- 2024-01-10.csv - File size:502kb
- 2024-01-11.csv - File size:284kb

Studio2_Folder

- 2024-01-10.csv - File size:183kb
- 2024-01-11.csv - File size:262kb

Studio3_Folder

- 2024-01-10.csv - File size:22kb
- 2024-01-11.csv - File size:22kb

(nothing broadcast from this studio during this time)

**Output**

CombinedCSV_Folder

- 2024-01-10.csv
- 2024-01-11.csv

Combined file with all info, sorted to value of time in file. Files to be read as one file by the playout program, resulting in one document per report to client.

This is what I have tried:

- Manually copy, paste and sort - very time consuming.
- Using parts of code available on forums - code combined all files in one folder to a single file,not from separate folders to one. Code in other programming languages (Panda/Python)
- Command prompt combining CSV files `*.csv > combined.csv` - does not solve the multiple file, multiple folder scenario.
- Excel macro record - requires a workaround due to same file names that conflict and cannot be opened.. Open file 1 and copy, close file1. Open file 2, paste file1 into file2, sort 1 column save as newfile1.

Code of macro:

```
Sub CSV_Record_Macro()

' CSV_Record_Macro Macro

' * Only two folders are used, until logic is sorted
' * CSV files usually about 90-120 files, in extreme case for log files possibly 1000 files
' * script should repeat for all CSV files in any of the folders
' * possibility exists that folder 3 will not always have data available due to not using it.
' * No headers, nots or other info to go into CSV files.

    ChDir "C:\CSV Testing\1WHK"
    Workbooks.OpenText Filename:="C:\CSV Testing\1WHK\2024-01-01.csv", Origin:= _
        xlWindows, StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:= _
        xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False _
        , Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar:="$", FieldInfo _
        :=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    
'Range should be for all cells with content
    Range("A1:A951").Select
    Selection.Copy

'Close file after copy, Excel Error for opening file with same name
   ActiveWindow.Close
   ChDir "C:\CSV Testing\2SWK"
    Workbooks.OpenText Filename:="C:\CSV Testing\2SWK\2024-01-01.csv", Origin:= _
        xlWindows, StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:= _
        xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False _
        , Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar:="$", FieldInfo _
        :=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    
'copied info should paste at end of file
   ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=87
    Range("A116").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Range("A88").Activate

'sorting column (there is only one) according to time info
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("2024-01-01").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("2024-01-01").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range( _
        "A88:A1066"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("2024-01-01").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:A1066")
        .Header = xlNo
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

'save as new CSV in Combined file folder, with the same DATE name to be read by playout software
    ChDir "C:\CSV Testing\CombinedxCSV"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\CSV Testing\CombinedxCSV\2024-01-01.csv" _
        , FileFormat:=xlCSVUTF8, CreateBackup:=False
' File used to start macro recording
    Windows("CSV Combine 240111.xlsx").Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: Power Query is made for stuff like this:  _Data > Get Data > From File > From Folder_.  You can then turn the file names (2024-01-10.csv) into real dates to filter the files and combine them all into a single file.

Comment: @KJ

1st Post:
Yes. all info combined, info don't have any header, just "one liners" with semi-colon delimiter 
Info sorting is by first values (time) ,the file name is the date.  There should not be duplicate audio info on the same time, as the studios don't broadcast simultaneously - there is always a human factor.
Duplicate info possibilities is system info, that happens on all systems at the same time - this info is not relevant to this situation.

Comment: @KJ

2nd Post:
Correct.

Will read up on a Batch File solution.

https://1drv.ms/f/s!As62ZpNvgbGBgYoe-rmmC2PIsSgB3Q?e=Amolpn

Folder 1 + 2 - actual data, folder 3 - made up data as example.

Combined folder  - result of manual copy/paste.

Answer (score 0):

I've set up three folders containing two csv files each.
Each file contains this data:  *13:16; data1; data2; data3; data4*

- Select *Get Data > From File > From Folder*
  [image]
- Navigate to your parent folder and select Open.
  [image]
- Select *Transform Data*
  [image]
- Expand the *Content* column by clicking the two-arrows on the right of the column header.
  [image]
- Click *OK* on the *Combine Files* dialog.
  This will combine the data from the files and keep the file name:
  [image]
- On the right of the screen in the *Applied Steps* section select the *Removed Other Columns1* entry.  As with Excel this will display the "formula" used at the top of the screen:
  `= Table.SelectColumns(#"Renamed Columns1", {"Source.Name", "Transform File"})`
  Add *Folder Path* to this:
  `= Table.SelectColumns(#"Renamed Columns1", {"Source.Name", "Transform File", "Folder Path"})`
- Re-select the last entry in the Applied Steps to see your data.
  [image]
- Select the *Source.Name* column and *Replace Values* on the *Home* tab.
  Replace `.csv` with nothing.
  [image]
- Select the *ABC* on the left of the *Source_Name* column header and change it to *Date*.
  [image]
- Select the *Folder Path* column and *Extract > Text Between Delimiters*
  [image]
- Add a `\` as the start and end delimiter, then select *Advanced Options* and *Scan for start delimiter* from the end of the input and skip 1 delimiter.  Then *Scan for the end delimiter* from the start delimiter toward the end of input and skip 0 delimiters.
  [image]
- Finally, on the Home tab click *Close and Load*
  [image]

Answer (score 0):

When tackling a data processing problem you first need to establish an aim (goal) before spending time programming with unknown quality of data.
[image]

Using the supplied sample data we can see there is no problem whatsoever with sorting (as that is done by the report generator). What is wrong is clearly double entries thus you need to start with cleaning the source data before merging.

Thus you should be addressing why there may be overlapping times from the seperate sources and remove those entries that are not valid for the result

[image]

Comment: Explaining why info is overlapping:

2 instances of the program runs in 2 different towns ( studios)
thus all the logs relating to updates of libraries ( Scheduler, System) will ahve duplicates, as every station does the same updates on the playlists.

For the output, only the advert information is vent to the day.
there should not be duplicates of any advertisements, as the systems don't play simultaneously.

System 1 = 05:30 - 14:00
System 2 = 14:00  -18:00
System 1 = 18:00-22:00

System 3 = Adhoc ,and will replace one of the above when it tasks its broadcasting spot.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your inputs, insights and assistance.

I am taking note of the comments by @KJ and
@Darren Bartrup-Cook

The final product:
Use a Batch File - as below (not my work,using bits and pieces)

Still working on the VBA to clean up the CSV files, although the cleanup is not needed for the purpose.

```
    @echo off
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "sourceFolder=C:\CSV Testing"
set "outputFolder=Reports_Afr"
set "referenceFolder=1-WHK"

if not exist "%sourceFolder%\%outputFolder%" (
    mkdir "%sourceFolder%\%outputFolder%"
)

for %%F in ("%sourceFolder%\%referenceFolder%\*.csv") do (
    set "filename=%%~nF"
    set "extension=%%~xF"
    set "outputFile=%sourceFolder%\%outputFolder%\!filename!.csv"
    
    copy "%%F" "!outputFile!" /Y

    attrib -r "!outputFile!" 2>nul

    for %%I in (2-SWK 3-OB) do (
        set "otherFile=%sourceFolder%\%%I\!filename!.csv"
        if exist "!otherFile!" (
            type "!otherFile!" >> "!outputFile!"
        )
    )
)

echo "CSV files merged successfully."
pause
```